# Allow access permission to write in Program Files of Windows 7

Tags: c#

My application throws 'Access denied' errors when writing temporary files in the installation directory where the executable resides. However it works perfectly well in Windows XP. How to provide access rights to Program Files directory in Windows 7?

EDIT:
How to make the program ask the user to elevate rights? (ie run program with full admin rights)

Comment: It does only work in XP if you haven't properly tested it (installed as Administrator, used by standard users). Stuff like that has been discouraged now for many years, you should fix your application instead of hacking around.

Comment: Do you mean it is because I'm doing some shoddy coding? Is so, pls explain so that I can improve.

Comment: Gergo Dries gives the correct answer below. Does your program actually need elevated privileges? Or are you trying to elevate privileges to support an unadvisable practice (i.e., writing temporary files to a directory where temporary files don't belong)?

Comment: You have a lot of correct answers already. I'm only saying that your assertion that "it works perfectly well in XP" is wrong, and probably comes from not testing your app under a limited account. Which you should do. You could try the Standard User Analyzer (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc766021(WS.10).aspx) to find the problematic areas of your application.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. I understand that my xp installation had full admin privileges for the account i use.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Your program should not write temporary files (or anything else for that matter) to the program directory. Any program should use %TEMP% for temporary files and %APPDATA% for user specific application data. This has been true since Windows 2000/XP so you should change your aplication.

The problem is not Windows 7.

You can ask for appdata folder path:

```
string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

or for TEMP path

```
string dir = Path.GetTempPath()
```

Comment: 100% correct! More info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/77aaf6e1-8de5-4529-9b26-fa89b55fcc49

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's not an answer at all, does windows knows the meaning of "backward compatibility"? if you created an application that was working well on windows XP why will it crash or even require any other specific new permissions to run on new systems, it's crazy to try to think of "maybe"s on your application in case MS decide that they will restrict X o Y now and your application relies on that. Instead MS should say "ok, you program files will be working as it's, but here's the NewProgramFiles folder which will help you to, blah blah blah".

Comment: His questition was `how to provide access rights`.  Your answer says bacicly, "`don't`".  It, however does not answer his original question.

Answer (score 29):

Your program has to run with Administrative Rights.  You can't do this automatically with code, but you can request the user (in code) to elevate the rights of your program while it's running. There's a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation) on how to do this. Alternatively, any program can be run as administrator by right-clicking its icon and clicking "Run as administrator".

However, I wouldn't suggest doing this.  It would be better to use something like this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

to get the AppData Folder path and create a folder there for your app.  Then put the temp files there.

Comment: @n0vic3c0d3r I added a wiki reference for you.  Hopefully that helps!

Comment: In case of errors add Enviroment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Answer (score 12):

Options I can think of:

- Run entire app as full admin priv. using UAC

  Run a sub-process as full admin for only those things needing access

  **Write temporary files elsewhere**

Answer (score 8):

Add new item in the project: Application Manifest and save it.

Now open this file and look for `<requestExecutionLevel>`. It must be set to `asInvoker`.

Change it to `highestAvailable`. Now on executing your application, a prompt will appear asking for permission. Click `yes`!

Thats all :) now you can write and read from the system32 or any other file which requires admin right

You can verify your application by [sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx).

```
sigcheck.exe -m yourapp.exe
```

And in the output check for element requestedExecutionLevel.

Comment: im not sure, it got couple of years for me to respond, Sorry for that :)

Comment: Upvote because this is the answer. Because what if the application the person is asking about could be an installer that needs to write to program files?

Comment: Well that exactly my thought processed :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't cause a .Net application to elevate its own rights.  It's simply not allowed.  The best you can do is to specify elevated rights when you spawn another process.  In this case you would have a two-stage application launch.

Stage 1 does nothing but prepare an elevated spawn using the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo object and the Start() call.

Stage 2 is the application running in an elevated state.

As mentioned above, though, you very rarely want to do this.  And you certainly don't want to do it just so you can write temporary files into %programfiles%.  Use this method only when you need to perform administrative actions like service start/stop, etc.  Write your temporary files into a better place, as indicated in other answers here.

Answer (score 4):

Another way round it would be to stop UAC then restart it.  Create a CMD file with the following code;

Rem Stop UAC
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
rem force reboot
Start ShutDown /R /F /T 30

You'll need to right click on the CMD file and use run as admin. once you have finished what you are doing restart UAC with the following code (no need to use run as admin this time);

%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

rem force reboot
Start ShutDown /R /F /T 30

The down sides to using this method is have to right click and use run as admin to close UAC down and you have to reboot for it to take effect.

BTW there are several reasons why you would need to write to the forbidden areas...the first two that springs to mind would be to run a batch file to append host to prevent your browser going to dodgy sites or to copy license keys in a silent install.

Comment: This is the only answer that mentions that UAC can be involved in the denial of access, as opposed to just a lack of ACLs.  Therefore it's the only answer which reflects on the operating systems part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot agree with arguments, that it is better to write all files in other directories, e.g., %APPDATA%, it is only that you cannot avoid it, if you want to avoid running application as administrator on Windows 7.

It would be much cleaner to keep all application specific data (e.g. ini files) in the same folder as the application (or in sub folders) as to speed the data all over the disk (%APPDATA%, registry and who knows where else). This is just Microsoft idea of clean programming. Than of course you need registry cleaner, disk cleaner, temporary file cleaner, ... instead of e+very clean practice - removing the application folder removes all application specific data (exep user data, which is normally somewhere in My Documents or so).

In my programs I would prefer to have ini files in application directory, however, I do not have them there, only because I cannot have them there (on Windows).

Comment: This practice is hardly unique to Windows.  For example, the Unix paradigm of splitting file I/O into /bin, /var, /tmp, and /usr is several decades old.  Also, the notion that placing files in the same filesystem directory will make them physically adjacent is terribly ignorant.

Comment: `-1` - I disagree with your disagreement.  The problem is bad programmers who don't listen to the rules.  Stay out of the Registry and you will never need a Registry Cleaner.  Properly delete temporary files when you are finished with them and you will never need a Temp File Cleaner.  Not having standard user access into various folders is the correct design, you don't want unauthorized people or malware messing around with certain OS and application folders.  It is not difficult at all to follow the rules.  I refuse to install software that fails to follow the rules.

Comment: @RichardBerg Does Unix also generally prevent programs from writing to the directories where they are running from?

Comment: @Dronz yes. 
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ ls -ld /usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 57344 Apr 25 22:44 /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an alternate solution to all these problems.... 
Make an two level application. As said above...

1) Launcher which will launch another Main App using code such as (VB)

```
Call ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", App.Path & "\MainApp.exe", 0, 0, vbNormalFocus)
```

2) Main App, which is writing to protected areas, ie Program Files folder

I've successfully tried this with windows 7

I'm also developing an app which has online update feature. But it doesn't work in Vista/W7..

I agree with other peoples about Microsoft Policies and Standard Practices.

**But my Question is ..
1) How to apply update to an existing application, which probably always remain in Program Files folder.
2) There might be some way to do this, otherwise how goolge updater, antivirus updater or any software updater workes?**

> I need answer to my questions..... :o

Prof. Rajendra Khope
(MIT, Pune, India)

Comment: To Rajendra: To update your existing application (e.g. in c:\program files\your application\), you need a seperate update program to do that. you need to elevate the updater program to runas administrator, in your updater, you can do whatever you want, like downloading files from Internet, replacing files in application folder. check the following link for how to elevate your program for launching.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/dd400cb9-d5fc-41b2-ad9d-6b91ce88c766

Comment: The question targets `C#` not `VB`

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a program just install it in `C:\`, not in Program Files. I had a lot of problems when I was installing Android SDK. My problem got solved  by installing it in `C:\`.

Answer (score 1):

While M$ "best practices" is to not write data into the %programfiles% folder; I sometimes do.  I do not think it wise to write temporary files into such a folder; as the TEMP environment variable might e.g. point to a nice, fast, RAM drive.

I do not like to write data into %APPDATA% however.  If windows gets so badly messed up that one needs to e.g. wipe it and reinstall totally, perhaps to a different drive, you might lose all your settings for nearly all your programs.  I know.  I've done it many times.  If it is stored in %programfiles%, 1) it doesn't get lost if I e.g. have to re-install Windows on another drive, since a user can simply run the program from its directory, 2) it makes it portable, and 3) keeps programs and their data files together.

I got write access by having my installer, Inno Setup, create an empty file for my INI file, and gave it the users-modify setting in the [Files] section.  I can now write it at will.

Comment: `-1` - Don't store settings files in ProgramFiles. Ever.  If Windows needs to be totally wiped then everything in ProgramFiles is wiped as well, so your argument is wrong.  Your app should always re-create its default settings file (ini, xml, etc.) in the AppData folder on a new install.  If I ever install an app that does not follow the rules, it gets uninstalled and never used again.

Comment: @deegeem Program Files does NOT get wiped when re-installing Windows.  Putting app settings in the same folder as the executable has merit for the reasons specified above.  Microsoft's "best practices" for this stem from security and avoiding access permission security holes.  Writing to the app install folder doesn't mean you will have a security flaw, but it could be more likely.

Comment: Writing to the program files folder makes an app portable.  It's also really nice if yer registry ever gets trashed, or you reinstall windows.  I would copy the apps in Program Files that were portable, and reinstall Windows; although deegeem says they don't get trashed.  That may change.  That way, my settings would be preserved.

Comment: If you want to make your app portable (all in one folder) then you should install it on %appdata% and not %programFiles%, this way you have write permissions. If you want you app to be to allUsers and share app settings/data you should use %programData% folder to write your settings/data

Comment: I have an app that can share data between all users, being installed in the %programfiles% folder, or for individual users, in %appdata% - more due to the limitations of users running a user account than an admin acct. I myself like being able to go into "Program Files" and see what is installed on a machine; for space management purposes and just general information. Whether I install to %programfiles% or %programData%, I can give all users access to data directories I create as a user, and to I see no permissions advantage to the latter (if the reason for your downvote), except M$ says so.

Comment: Actually, there is probably no need for an %appdata% install, since I can indeed create directories in %programFiles% that all users can access, installing from a user acct.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for answers. I found only one.

None of these work for me. I am not trying to write temporary files, unless this is defined as nonsystem files. Although I am designated the admin on my user profile, with full admin rights indicated in the UAC, I cannot write to program files or windows. This is very irritating.

I try to save an image found online directly to the windows/web/wallpaper folder and it won't let me. Instead, I must save it to my desktop (I REFUSE to navigate to "my documents/pictures/etc" as I refuse to USE such folders, I have my own directory tree thank you) then, from the desktop, cut and paste it to the windows/web/wallpaper folder. And you are telling me I should do that and smile? As an admin user, I SHOULD be able to save directly to its destination folder. My permissions in drive properties/security and in directory properties/security say I can write, but I can't. Not to program files, program files (86) and windows.

How about saving a file I just modified for a game in Program Files (86) (name of game) folder. It won't let me. I open the file to modify it, I can't save it without first either saving it to desktop etc as above, or opening the program which is used for modifying the file first as admin, which means first navigating all the way over to another part of the directory tree where I store those user mod programs, then within the program selecting to open file and navigate again to the file I could have just clicked on to modify in the first place from my projects folder, only to discover that this won't work either! It saves the file, but the file cannot be located. It is there, but invisible. The only solution is to save to desktop as above.

I shouldn't have to do all this as an admin user. However, if I use the true admin account all works fine. But I don't want to use the real admin account. I want to use a user account with admin rights. It says I have admin rights, but I don't.

And, finally, I refuse to store my portables in %appdata%. This is not how I wish to navigate through my directory tree. My personal installations which I use as portables are stored in the directory I create as a navigation preference.

So, here is the tried and true answer I have found:

From what I have seen so far.... unless one uses the real admin account, these permissions just aren't ever really available to any other user with admin privileges in the Windows Vista and Windows 7 OS's. While it was simple to set admin privileges in Windows XP, later versions have taken this away for all but those who can comfortably hack around.

Comment: Please edit your answer, to make the part which actually answers (the very last paragraph, I think) more prominent. The larger part of your answer seems reasoning why you think that this it the only answer. Adding that might make some sense, the way you structured your answer however puts you in danger of getting "not-an-answer" flags. In my opinion, you should also reduce the reasoning part drastically. Otherwise welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for trying to help. Take the [tour] at your convenience, for getting lots of helpful information on how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a program that saves its data properly to %APPDATA%, but sometimes, there are system-wide settings that affect all users. So in these situations, it HAS to write to the programs installation directory.

And as far as I have read now, it's impossible to temporarily get write access to one directory. You can only run the whole application as administrator (which should be out of the question) or not be able to save that file. (all or nothing)

I guess, I will just write the file to %APPDATA% and launch an external program that copies the file into the installation folder and have THAT program demand admin privileges... dumb idea, but seems to be the only practical solution...

Comment: For system-wide settings that affect all users, store the file(s) in CommonApplicationData. See MSDN Environment.SpecialFolders page: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) and see: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an **access to IIS User** for folders of Website or Web Application that you want write or rewrite in it.

Answer (score -5):

It would be neater to create a folder named "c:\programs writable\" and put you app below that one. That way a jungle of low c-folders can be avoided.

The underlying trade-off is security versus ease-of-use. If you know what you are doing you want to be god on you own pc. If you must maintain healthy systems for your local anarchistic society, you may want to add some security.

Comment: I agree, this is not a great suggestion at all.