# vim and cream windows 7 access privileges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, vim

I recently installed cream onto a windows 7 laptop. I was installing the rails.vim plugin when tried to issue the :helptags ~/vim/docs command so I can have the rails helpfiles available.

I have since discovered that w7 doesn't allow user privileges in the program files directory so I haven't been able to add the helptags or use edit -> startup settings to change my vimfiles.

I found this thread here [Allow access permission to write in Program Files of Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946420/allow-access-permission-to-write-in-program-files-of-windows-7) and a few websites referring to "ultimate windows tweaker" . Has anyone without third party software been able to get access rights for vim or cream on win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a how-to here [Take ownership Win 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm) on how to grant user access to a folder and subfolders, which will allow me to set the ~/vim folder and subs to have write access.

Comment: I have tested this and it allows full writing for cream to save settings I now have :help rails available

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access privileges to the vim folder, then you should rather try a portable version of vim (try gvimportable from http://www.portableapps.com).

The access control has been designed such that multiple users can share a software and not modify it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, on windows XP at least, you can put your vim files in your $HOME directory in a subdirectory called 'vimfiles'.

And you shoud have read/write access to that directory.

If you want to check where Vim is looking for config files in runtime, use
:echo &rtp

You should at least see the default system wide vim directory and your home directory.

If this is a personal install, you'd better put everything in your home.

Have you tried ?

:helptags $HOME/vimfiles/doc

Comment: Also see `:help 'runtimepath'` :-)